# Why does print(3 > 0 == True) show False?

Tags: python, operator-precedence, comparison-operators

The order precedence of python comparison operators is left to right. With this, `print(3 > 0 == True)` shows False, but the equivalent statement: `print((3 > 0) == True)` shows True.
Additionally, `print(3 > (0 == True))` shows True.

So why is it that `print(3 > 0 == True)` shows False?

My python version is 3.8.2.

Comment: They are *not* equivalent statements. `x > y == z` is not equivalent to *either* `(x>y) == z` or `x > (y == z)`. Comparison operators are not associative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is this:

The value `3 > 0 == True` is interpreted as `(3>0) AND (0==True)` which gives `True AND False` which is of course `False`

This is why for example the statement: `3 > 1 == True` evaluates to `True`

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons where comparisons can be chained.